# java service could not be initialized (debugging help)

Tags: java

I have a jar package that I wrote using netbeans. This package is called from other java file. The jar calls a webservice and is supposed to do something with it. Now everything works fine locally. I compiled the files and locally and uploaded them to the server and when I run it, I get the "Service could not be initialized".I am not sure how to debug this. I am pretty new to java. What is the best approach here to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by implementing logging (I like log4J) in your project so you can get some better details of what is actually going wrong. This will be very useful not only now but in the future as things go wrong (they inevitably will) you will be able to solve them based on how good of a job you did logging what is happening in your application. Right now it sounds like an error is bubbling up and you're not getting much detail about it. Logging should help you determine not only what went wrong but where it happened and what the application was doing at the time.

Try this [short introduction to log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) to get started.